# ORACLE - how to use a CASE WHEN EXISTS statement for rows that do not exist?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am given the following tables

table 1:

```
ID  Amount_week_1
05   350
```

table 2:

```
ID  Amount_week_2
```

There are no rows displayed for table 2 as 0 amount was made. However, I would like to combine these info into a new table which looks something like

```
ID  Amount_week_1  Amount_week_2
05      350             0
```

May I know how can I go about doing this? I have tried using the EXISTS clause but i might have used it wrongly since it didnt work.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Did you try to use left join?

Comment: Yes I do have a left join. But it still doesnt solve the problem because table 2 returns no rows at all. So what im looking for is a method that will return '0' for tables with no rows.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `LEFT JOIN` to combine the two tables.

```
SELECT table1.id, table1.amount_week_1
     , NVL(table2.amount_week_2, 0) as amount_week_2
FROM   table1
LEFT JOIN table2 on table2.ID = table1.ID
```

Comment: OP tagged 'oracle'. So `NVL` instead of `isNULL`

Comment: @RobertKock sorry i did not notice the tagged

Comment: Use `COALESCE` and forget about database tags.